# While development, how to check if the coredata versioning is working?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, core-data-migration

I have added one more entity to the existing coreData and I have enabled `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` flag as well. As I have added an entity, I guess! there is no need to define custom mapping of versions.

So I rerun the app with version 2 being selected, but gave a crash with no log.
Could you help me in how to test versioning?

Thanks in advance,
Venkat.

Answer (score 0):

Rerunning the app worked when I supplied with two flags. I.e., `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption`.

If it can auto migrate, then it works with rerun, else we need to write mapping and migration manager coder accordingly.

Regards,
Venkatarao N.